# A Dockerfile doesn't install RUN dependencies

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '3.7'
  services:
    php:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: php:7.3-rc-fpm
      container_name: php_7.3-rc-fpm
      volumes:
        - .:/var/www/app
      restart: unless-stopped
      working_dir: /var/www
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-rc-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  mysql-client \
  locales \
  zip \
  vim \
  unzip \
  git \
  curl


# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip pcntl

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www
```

Started containers with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and when I execute

```
docker-compose exec php bash
```

followed by

```
mysql --version
```

result in

```
bash: mysql: command not found
```

the `mysql-client` is missing and the others RUNs installation as well...

Any idea what is going on?

....and stackoverflow need more details to approve my edit when I don't have any ............

Comment: Shouldn't it be `docker exec php bash`?

Comment: The bash is working fine

Comment: Can give us the whole procedure? How did you start the php service with docker-compose ? How is the current directory structured ?

Comment: @godot edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image: php:7.3-rc-fpm` should be dropped.

It tells docker-compose to build from the "php_7.3-rc-fpm" image and not from the image build with your Dockerfile (it's a question of precedence). So it's normal that nothing you ask to install in the Dockerfile is available...

I tested to be sure and indeed, if you drop this line, the commands `docker-compose exec php bash` followed by `mysql --version` gives you what you expected.

Comment: Small note, if you look at [this docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference), you'll see it says something contradictory:

  >   "If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image".


But this is not my experience (I had already noticed that before). Maybe there's something I don't get or the documentation is not up-to-date...

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing container image name. In your `docker-compose.yml` you tell:

```
services:
    php:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: php:7.3-rc-fpm
```

That you want to build your own image and name it **php:7.3-rc-fpm**! But this is not your image' name - it is the name of a well-known php docker container! And in your `Dockerfile` you inherits from it:

```
FROM php:7.3-rc-fpm
```

So, you are overwriting public image but your own. And I can only guess, what will be the new image like.. 
Solution - remove `image` from your `docker-compose` file. It is not the image to be used, it is the name you want to give your image after being built, upon used in conjunction with `build` properties.